# Problem with reading and decoding a serial port in python

Tags: python, serial-port

Right now I'm using the python serial module to read a serial port. I'm using putty to send my own computer some values to test this program. I'm able to read and write from my serial port without a problem. The only thing I have a problem with is when I decode my read value from the serial port. It seems to change the value some how which causes me to not be able to use logic like "while" and "if". It acts as if its a different value than what I get if I print it out. For example if I send an A to the serial port and print out the DecodeVal in the below code it would give me an 'A', but it would not break me out of the while loop. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
import serial
import time

def main():
     DecodeVal = 0
     ser1 = serial.Serial('COM7',2400,timeout=1)     

     while(DecodeVal != "A"):
            time.sleep(5)
            ReadVal = ser1.read(1000)
            DecodeVal = ReadVal.decode('utf-8')
            print(DecodeVal)

     print('broke out')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try ReadVal.decode('utf-8').strip().

Comment: Nope still not working, plus now when I print out that value I get the following.<built-in method strip of str object at 0x0330C9A0>

Comment: Could you please show more lines from your code, particulary where your print statement is?

Comment: I edited the code above. I'm basically printing what has been received on the serial port in the last 5 seconds. I want to loop through that until I receive a certain character in this case 'A'.

Comment: Maybe `DecodeVal` is more than one character? Try `while "A" not in DecodeVal:`

Comment: @MarkRansom That did work, thanks. I never knew about the function of 'not in' in python. Why am I not able to print out all the data that is stored in DecodeVal? It will most likely be of great use to know that information when I start doing  more complex things with serial ports like I plan to.

Comment: Maybe the extra characters can't be seen, like `\r` or `\n`.

Comment: @MarkRansom How could I be so stupid...putty is sending \r on every message. When I adjust the while statement to account for that it works. Thanks for the help! It should of been super obvious, but, oh well, that's how you learn :)

Comment: Glad you found it. You might find `.strip()` to be useful.